# Oracle SQL - Case statement with iteration

Tags: sql, oracle

The ASCII table values should be compared to the s.manure_type. For each record in the following table below the QuantityText case statement should do a comparison. The value it needs to select is e.g. oats,velvet beans, other none.

```
select                        
c.id customer_num,
c.type type, 
s.id_text sample_num,
c.sasa_grower_code s_grower,
c.address s_address1,
c.postalcode s_post_code,
c.email q1_email,
nvl(c.client_name, c.farm_name )s_company,
c.farm_name s_estate,
c.contact_name s_contact,
s.id_numeric id_numeric,
s.id_text fas_lab_id,
s.date_received received_date,
s.date_printed printed_date,
s.sampled_date sampled_date,
e.name S_AREA_DESCRIP,
a.name s_advisor_name,
a.email s_advisor_email,
s.order_no s_order_num,
s.field_name s_field,
p.phrase_text  || ' cm' sample_depth,
cr.crop_name s_crop,
s.attyield s_yield,
s.variety s_varty, 
case when s.flg_trashed is null then 
               'None'
             else (case when s.flg_trashed = constant_pkg.get_true  then 
                     'Yes'
                   else (case when s.flg_trashed = constant_pkg.get_false then 
                          'No'
                         else ' ' 
                         end)
                   end) end trashed,
case when s.flg_irrigated is null then 
               'None'
             else (case when s.flg_irrigated = constant_pkg.get_true then 
                     'Yes'
                   else (case when s.flg_irrigated = constant_pkg.get_false then 
                          'No'
                         else ' ' 
                         end)
                   end) end s_irrig,     
                   CASE
                        WHEN trim(s.manure_type) in (select p.phrase_id from phrase p where p.phrase_type = 'AL_G_MANUR') then (select p.phrase_text from phrase p)
                    END AS QuantityText,                  
'' S_GM_YIELD,
s.project_code project_code,
s.trial_ref trial_ref,
s.cost_centre cost_centre
from client c
left outer join sample s on (s.client_id = c.id)
left outer join extension e on (e.id = c.extension_id)
left outer join advisor a on (a.id = c.advisor_id)
left outer join phrase p on (p.phrase_id = s.depth)
left outer join crop cr on (cr.id = s.crop_id)
where p.phrase_type = phrase_pkg.get_soil_depth
and c.id =    '211493A'
and s.fas_sample_type =  sample_pkg.get_soil_sample
and s.flg_recommendation = sample_pkg.get_flg_recommendation
and s.id_numeric between   14932  and  14933
```

```
+----------------------------+
|           Phrase           |
+----------------------------+
|AL_G_MANUR  OA Oats         |
|AL_G_MANUR  V  Velvet Beans
|AL_G_MANUR  O  Other
|AL_G_MANUR  N  None         |
+----------------------------+
```

But I get the error ORA-00900: Single row query returns more than one row

Comment: The problem is in the last CASE expression.

Answer (score 0):

Missing where clause in one of the case statements is most likely the cause.

```
CASE
  WHEN trim(s.manure_type) in 
      (select p.phrase_id from phrase p where p.phrase_type = 'AL_G_MANUR') 
    then (select p.phrase_text from phrase p) <<< NO WHERE CLAUSE ?
END AS QuantityText,
```

This is relatively easy to debug yourself.

1. Remove a single selected column
2. Check if error still occurs
3. If it does, go back to 1.
4. If it does not then verify why last added column errors

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the following statement

```
then (select p.phrase_text from phrase p)
```

I guess, It should be replaced with this

```
(select p.phrase_text from phrase p where p.phrase_type = 'AL_G_MANUR')
```